# Python Selenium Instagram Bot

Tags: python, instagram, bots

I'm building now Instagram bot and I have a question.
I want the bot to keep hitting like on the pictures in my feed.
I did something like this:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('article._8Rm4L:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > section:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)').click()
time.sleep(3)
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('article._8Rm4L:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > section:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)').click()
time.sleep(3)
```

And it keeps going like this, there is any way I can do it easier than write 1,2,3,4...

Answer (score 0):

You must add scrolling to it in order to continue liking images in the feed

My code:

```
         SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5
             # Get scroll height
              last_height = self.driver.execute_script("return 
              document.body.scrollHeight")
              while true:
             # Scroll down to bottom


            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo
           (0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
# Wait to load page
sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
# Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
new_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

last_height = new_height
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Could you please also fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath it is better => find_element_by_xpath()
Or
You can use selenium IDE to record evey thing and save it python file to edit it.